# How to regulate height of LIs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a UL where the LIs are boxes.  I want the boxes to all be the same size, but sometimes the boxes are one line, and other times they're two.  how do i add an extra empty line in the LI if the content is only one line?  I'm assuming this will be some sort of javascript?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just give them all a certain 'height' or 'min-height' attribute instead of trying to fix a height that is automatically rendered to them.

Try posting some of your html so we can help you more though...

Comment: hi gillyb- thanks for your answer.  It works in FF.  What do you mean by _height for ie6, though?  would i put 
    min_height:2em;
for the ie6-specific CSS?

Comment: great, i got it to work; it's just _height.  only thing is, em doesn't work, only px.  why is that?

Comment: no, you would just write _height:2em; for ie6.
IE6 I think is the only browser that considers CSS class names that start with an underscore ('_'), so this works only in IE6, and it works the same as min-height property in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your HTML markup, you could use CSS `height` or `min-height` properties. The latter will only work in the latest browsers, e.g. not IE6.

Comment: in IE6 you cadd the CSS property '_height' - it's a hack that works like min-height in other browsers just for IE6!

Comment: @gillyb I don't advocate hacks. You should look into IE6 conditional comments. Otherwise, your answer was the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could suffice?

```
line-height: 2em
```